# How to automate the master merge after releases for Continuous Delivery

Tags: merge, git-flow, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

What is the best practice of automation of master merge?
Right now we are doing it manually. Should we do it from the CD(vsts) pipeline using a merge task? What happens in case of a merge failure?

This is the merge task we have found in the marketplace. Which is not working as expected.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dtzar.git-merge

[image]

Comment: Do you mean CD on release branch and auto merge release branch into master branch after deployment on release branch? But the branching model you referred is actually treat master branch as the main/production branch and record each release version by tag (such as 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 etc). And the release branch**es are** actually prepare for every releases separately. So you should CD on master branch.

Comment: agree that master should be the production but how to merge to the master from the pipeline is asked. Updated the question for clarity

Comment: I add an answer for merging master branch automatically, you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge other branches into `master` branch automatically by Powershell script. Details as below:
Add a **Powershell task** in the end of the release definition, with the scripts:

```
git clone https://<alternate username>:<Alternate password>@account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/reponame repo
cd repo
git checkout $(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCHNAME)
git checkout master
git merge $(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCHNAME) -X ours -m 'merge $(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCHNAME) into master'
git push origin master
```

**Note:** for the workflow, there mainly has no conflicts for merging branches into `master`. the `-X ours` option for git merge is using the `master` version if there has conflicts. And you can also use `-X theris` instead to make the conflicts use the source branch's version.

[image]

Comment: Can you merge master branch automatically by the PowerShell task?